# Google map Blue-Dot for current location in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps

I was implementing google maps..And i want the default google blue dot for the current location. can anyone please tell, how to do so, in reactjs or in simple javascript..

Answer (score 1):

First you have to allow the browser to send your Geo location to Google API, then wire up this code on the window/document load event :

```
var map, infoWindow;
function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
        zoom: 6
    });
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    // Try HTML5 geolocation.
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var pos = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };

            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
            infoWindow.open(map);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: pos,
                map: map,
                title: 'Hello World!',
                icon: 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/info-i_maps.png',
            });

            map.setCenter(pos);
        }, function () {
            //handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        });
    } else {
        // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
        //handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
}
```

Comment: i was reffering to gsm marker. any idea about that.

Comment: If you mean you want to change the shape of the marker, then you can use "icon" property to assign it to built in google marker images or you can use your own. I've updated the posted code.